# Given a set does there exist a topology on that set that makes it compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Say you are given a set X, does there always exist a non-trivial (not the coarse topology) topology on X such that X is

1) Comapact
2) Connected
3) Compact and Connected

Additionally, if it were possible can you give an example of such a topology on the set of Integers(where in the set of integers would be compact,connected)

Comment: Give $X$ the coarse topology, only $X$ and $\emptyset $ are open.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned I was looking for a non trivial topology.I'll edit the question to a add that phrase

Comment: Examples of countable connected Hausdorff spaces are given here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46986/countable-connected-hausdorff-space

Comment: The cofinite topology on a countable set is compact, connected and $T_1$ but not Hausdorff. The answer to (1) is trivial yes, given any (infinite) cardinal consider the [Alexandroff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of a discrete space of that cardinality:The result is compact Hausdorff (hence normal) but not connected. If $X$ is finite and $T_1$ then is is compact but not connected (only connected if $X$ is a singleton). There are finite $T_0$ spaces that are connected, with applications in [Digital topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_topology)

Comment: For countable connected Hausdorff spaces see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336578/countable-connected-hausdorff-space) and the earlier question to which it’s linked.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to rule out finite topologies, as well as the coarse topology.

Comment: For compact Hausdorff connected spaces we know that they contain a copy of the Cantor set (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38450/compact-hausdorff-spaces-without-isolated-points-in-zf) (connected is much stronger than having no isolated points) e.g. so there the cardinality couldn't be smaller than continuum.