# In Search of Topology Example(Counter-example)

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

So I found an interesting example of a topology a while back but I can't remember the exact properties it had so I am hoping if I describe the topology someone can link me to the topology I am after. It was a short paper that I had found.

The basic idea was points in the plane were used to form triangles by using rational endpoints on the x-axis. That is two points on the x-axis would form a base then a point in the plane would be used to form the triangle.

If I recall the space was Hausdorff but I don't remember the other properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re probably thinking of Bing’s Sticky Foot Space, which is an example of a countable, connected Hausdorff space. I described it in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336578/countable-connected-hausdorff-space), and the picture [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=frG9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=bing%27s+sticky+foot&source=bl&ots=uHsUUplYGN&sig=ACfU3U0hbm3_P0l2R7WxUr4NiOPdyUmX3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJtazjrdnoAhUPG80KHUaWBHMQ6AEwAXoECAsQKQ#v=onepage&q=bing's%20sticky%20foot&f=false) may also help.

Comment: That is it! Thank you

Comment: @all.over: You’re welcome!